# Почему когда я наследуюсь от абстрактных сервисов и контроллеров в nest.js перестает работать валидация в dto через class-validator

Tags: nestjs

Когда сервисы и контроллеры реализованы через абстрактные entity.service и entity.controller, перестает работать валидация через class-validator в DTO.

Пример когда не работает валидация:

```
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MinLength } from 'class-validator';

class MyController<MyCreateDto> {
  @Post('/create')
  create(@Body() dto: MyCreateDto) {
    return dto;
  }
}

class CreateDto {
  @MinLength(10)
  value: string;
}

@Controller('/test')
export class TestController extends MyController<CreateDto> {}
```